# OpenGL - Can I draw non-indexed when index-buffer is set for VAO?

Tags: opengl-4, vertex-buffer, vertex-attributes

I set up a VAO, binding vertex-buffers to it for vertex attributes, but also set index-buffer (With `glVertexArrayElementBuffer`). Does that restrict it so it only works with `glDrawElements` type of commands, or will it work with `glDrawArrays` too?
(Using OpenGL4.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that restrict it so it only works with glDrawElements type of commands?

No.

You can still use non-indexed draw calls like glDrawArrays. The question is whether your vertex topology suits that. glDrawArrays is essentially equal to an indexed draw call with indices [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...].